# Insert character into UNC string using Powershell replace

Tags: regex, powershell, replace, unc

We've been migrating multiple file servers into a consolidated black box solution and have a reason to copy certain files from the original source servers back across to the new solution, as there have been some issue recalling those files from archive (i.e. not often used files).

I've started writing code to identify the files

```
$v7Kitems = Get-ChildItem $parentpath -force | where {$_.attributes -match "Offline"} | Select FullName, DirectoryName
```

which puts the information into an array for me. The format of the UNC is `\\new_server\adminshare\old_server\original_drive\original_local_directory_structure\file`.

I wish to use replace option to create a new variable for the old file location, and then use Get-Item to copy the file back across, hence pulling back "DirectoryName" as well.

```
Foreach($item in $v7Kitems){
    $source=$item.FullName -replace "\\\\new_server\\adminshare\\","\\" -replace "\\[E-Z]\\","\<original_drive>$\"
}
```

I don't know what I should use for  in the replace section of `\\[E-Z]\\`, as the drive letter is not consistent across servers. The string length to this point is a consistent length. Maybe I should not use a RegEx replace, but some other type which captures the letter at character number of the drive letter, then inserts that as a variable in the replace string?

What are the Oracle of Overflow's thoughts?

Geoff

Comment: `-replace '\\([e-z])\\','\$1$\'`

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I've tried the alteration and this changes the output to `\\old_server\$\original_local_directory_structure\file`, which doesn't have the drive letter in place. Should I be trying to capture the drive letter as variable `$1`?

Comment: I might solve my own question, but `Foreach($item in $v7Kitems){
 $uncsplit = $item.FullName.split("\")
 $drive = $uncsplit[5]
 $source=$item.FullName -replace "\\\\new_server\\adminshare\\","\\" -replace "\\([e-z])\\","\$drive$\"
}` Seems to give the correct outputs. Is there any reason why this shouldn't work if the path construct is expected and consistent?

Comment: Where id the drive letter in the input string? If it is missing, the drive letter can only be hardcoded in the replacement.

Comment: @Geoff You used double quotes around the replacement expression (`"\$1$\"`). Please take another look at Mathias' comment and pay attention to the quotes used there. If you're going to use double quotes you need to escape the `$` in `$1` with a backtick.

Comment: @Ansgar, I will review. I use " in all my code unless otherwise required, so just altered the comments to maintain my own format without understanding the requirement to escape the first $. Thanks for notifying me of the difference.

Comment: I can't seem to mark up Mathias's first comment as the answer, but this works. I'm going to need to understand more the impact of using ' instead of ", and perhaps change my script writing methods.  `$parentpath='\\new_server\adminshare\'
$v7Kitems = @()
$v7Kitems = Get-ChildItem $parentpath -force -recurse | where {$_.attributes -match "Offline"} | Select FullName, DirectoryName
Foreach($item in $v7Kitems){
 $source=$item.FullName -replace '\\\\oldserver\\adminshare\\','\\' -replace '\\([e-z])\\','\$1$\'
Copy-Item $source -Destination $item.DirectoryName -Force}`

Comment: @Geoff You can't accept a comment as an answer because it's a comment, not an answer.

Answer (score 0):

As [Mathias](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38578727/insert-character-into-unc-string-using-powershell-replace#comment64546750_38578727) pointed out in his comment you need to put the drive letter match in a capturing group so you can replace it with a backreference to the match followed by a `$` character:

```
-replace '\\([e-z])\\','\$1$\'
```

Beware that you need need single quotes around the replacement expression, otherwise PowerShell would expand `$1` as an (empty) PowerShell variable before the regular expression engine gets to see the replacement string.